# Como iniciar uma variável corretamente?

Tags: c#, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Existe diferença entre essas duas formas de iniciar uma variável?

```
List<classeterapeutica> itens = new List<classeterapeutica>();
modelOff.classeterapeuticas.ToList();
```

ou

```
List<classeterapeutica> itens = modelOff.classeterapeuticas.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é uma questão de ser correto, mas inicializar uma variável com um valor para trocar esse valor na linha seguinte não faz sentido, então o segundo código é preferível. Só atribua um valor para uma variável se este valor será usado em algum lugar. Se ele for descartado sem uso é algo ruim.

Comment: então qual seria a lógica de se usar `new class();`? pois já vi muitos códigos assim.

Comment: Em um caso semelhante a este não tem. Muito código que tem por aí é mal escrito. Sempre tem que ver o contexto. Não existe fórmula mágica pra programar corretamente.